# UITableView works in iOS 7 but appears crushed in iOS 8

Tags: uitableview, ios7, ios8, xcode6-beta6

Still new to iOS programming here.  Have a UITableView that works perfect on iOS 7 but appears crushed in iOS 8. Multiple devices. Also exhibits the same problem/difference when using the simulators (iOS 7 vs. iOS 8 simulators).

I am on Xcode 6 beta 6, Yosemite beta 6, iOS 7.12 and iOS 8 beta 5.

I've made the code as simple and complete as possible to show the problem:

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return [self.numberOfDays count];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];

        NSLog (@"%li", (long)indexPath.row);

        UILabel *label;
        label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        label.text = @"Monday";

        return cell;
    }
```

Notice my NSLog statement.  There are 88 rows in my UIViewTable (0-87).

- When this table loads in iOS 7...

  - I get 12 lines in my console
  - Which makes since as that is the initial number of viewable rows
  - The table scrolls nice and smooth ... all is good with the world.
- When this table loads in iOS 8...

  - I get 88 lines in my console
  - Which doesn't make sense, to me anyway
  - The initial appearance of the Table looks good
  - e.g. the first 12 rows display correctly
  - The table does not scroll correctly.
  - rows 12-87 appear about 1 pixel tall.

The initial appearance of the table looks OK (e.g. the first 12 rows display correctly) until I attempt to scroll thru it. Then rows 12-87 appear about 1 pixel tall.

PLEASE HELP!

**OK - it was as simple as adding:
    tableView.rowHeight = 44;
after my static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; line.
I didn't need this is iOS 7, not sure why I need it in iOS 8.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - it was as simple as adding:

```
    tableView.rowHeight = 44;
```

after my

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
```

line. I didn't need this is iOS 7, not sure why I need it in iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution might work, but it will be better to implement heightForRowAtIndexPath method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
      return 44;
}
```

I have no idea why there is difference between iOS 7 and 8, perhaps someone else could shed some light on that?